# Chart does not exclude Month of results

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using Windows Forms to create a chart where I use `DateTime X` value

Method:

```
private void LoadChart(List<myViewModel> model)
        {

            Axis XA = userChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
            Axis YA = userChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
            Series S1 = userChart.Series[0];
            S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            var dates = model.Select(x => x.ActivityDate).ToList();
          

            var random = new Random();
            foreach (DateTime d in dates)
            {
                S1.Points.AddXY(d, random.Next(99) + 33);
            }


            S1.LegendText = "Year " + dt.Year;
            // move to the bottom center:

            userChart.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
            userChart.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            S1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
            XA.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            XA.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM";

            XA.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
            XA.Interval = 1;



            YA.IsInterlaced = true;
            YA.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            YA.InterlacedColor = Color.FromArgb(31, Color.LightSeaGreen);
        }
```

As you can see my X is based on a model that I received from database. So I add my dates to char as:

```
 var random = new Random();
            foreach (DateTime d in dates)
            {
                S1.Points.AddXY(d, random.Next(99) + 33);
            }
```

My date list equals to 10 registers:

```
1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
2/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
3/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
5/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
6/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
7/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
8/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
9/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
10/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
11/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

As you can see that list exclude `April` and the latest register is `November` , when I run the method it throw it as:

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BNHH.png)

As you can see April appears but is not in my list, am I missing something? Why April is there if it is not in my list? Regards

Comment: Who says April is there? Looks like a straight line from Mar to May

Comment: On the image April appears @CaiusJard

Comment: Maybe you want to use a [CustomLabels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.customlabelscollection) collection instead using the predefined interval feature.